# JavaFX Task changes state to fail everytime I want to get login info

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task

I am trying to make a login page in JavaFX with a little progress bar. But I everytime I want to check the credentials the Task fails and throws me into setOnFailed() method. I have no idea what makes it change it's state or how to make it work.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class Login extends Base_controller implements Initializable{
   private ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    private TextField username;
    private PasswordField password;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        // Setting structure and components
        Label username_lbl = new Label();
        Label password_lbl = new Label();
        username_lbl.setText("Username:");
        password_lbl.setText("Password:");

        username = new TextField();
        password = new PasswordField();

        //some code

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.getChildren().addAll(container0, container1, container2, container3);
        root.setSpacing(30);


        // button action listener
        test.setOnAction(e->{
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                root.getChildren().add(pb);
            });

            Task<Void> validatePassword = new Task<Void>(){
                @Override
                protected Void call() throws Exception {
                    validatePassword(password, username);
                    return null;
                }
            };

            validatePassword.setOnSucceeded(ee->{ // when it finishes successfully
                try {
                    root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove the progress bar
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                User = dbHandler.getPersonByUsername(username.getText()); // Set up global variable
                Role = dbHandler.getPersonRole(User.getEmail());
                MainStage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
                Parent parent = null;
                try {
                    parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/menu.fxml"));
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
                MainStage.setScene(scene);
                MainStage.setTitle("Menu | Administration of Musical Courses");
                MainStage.show();
            });

            validatePassword.setOnFailed(eee->{ // if it fails (that will be indicated by the returned alert message)
                System.out.println("Failed");
                try {
                    root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove it anyway but inform your user
                    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Wrong Password", ButtonType.OK);
                    alert.showAndWait();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            new Thread(validatePassword).start(); // add the task to a thread and start it
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Login | Administration of Musical Courses");

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // validate here in this method
    public void validatePassword(TextField password, TextField username)
        if (checkLogin()) {
            new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        }
    }

    public boolean checkLogin(){
        return BCrypt.checkpw(password.getText(), dbHandler.getLoginByUsername(username.getText()).getPassword());
    }
}
```

It always fails in the validatePassword method when getting the data from database. Is it possible that calling the database somehow makes the Task fail? How do I change the code to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A task enters the failed state if and only if an exception is thrown from the `call()` method. You can put `validatePassword.getException().printStackTrace()` in the `onFailed` handler to see the stack trace of the exception, which you can then [read to see what went wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450):

```
validatePassword.setOnFailed(eee->{ // if it fails (that will be indicated by the returned alert message)
    System.out.println("Failed");
    validatePassword.getException().printStackTrace();
    try {
        root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove it anyway but inform your user
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Wrong Password", ButtonType.OK);
        alert.showAndWait();
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

I do not really understand your `validatePassword()` method:

```
if (checkLogin()) {
    new Alert(...);
}
```

If `checkLogin()` returns true, this will create an `Alert`, but will not actually use it (what are you really intending here...?). Note that this method is called from the background thread (because it is called from the task's `call()` method), and it is illegal to create an `Alert` if you are not on the FX Application Thread. So I suspect this is causing the exception to be thrown, which is sending you into the `onFailed` handler: checking the stack trace will confirm this.

A more natural approach would be to have the task return a `Boolean` representing whether or not the login was successful, which you could then handle in the `onSucceeded` handler:

```
test.setOnAction(e->{
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        root.getChildren().add(pb);
    });

    Task<Boolean> validatePassword = new Task<Boolean>(){
        @Override
        protected Boolean call() throws Exception {
            return checkLogin();
        }
    };

    validatePassword.setOnSucceeded(ee->{ // when it finishes successfully
        // this cannot throw an exception, there is no need for a try-catch;
        root.getChildren().remove(pb); // remove the progress bar

        if (validatePassword.getValue()) {
            User = dbHandler.getPersonByUsername(username.getText()); // Set up global variable
            Role = dbHandler.getPersonRole(User.getEmail());
            MainStage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent parent = null;
            try {
                parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/menu.fxml"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            MainStage.setScene(scene);
            MainStage.setTitle("Menu | Administration of Musical Courses");
            MainStage.show();
        } else {
            // handle failed login... this is on the FX Application Thread so 
            // you can show an Alert...
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Wrong Password", ButtonType.OK);
            alert.show();
        }
    });

    validatePassword.setOnFailed(eee->{ 
        // exception was thrown trying to validate password
        validatePassword.getException().printStackTrace();
        // inform user something went wrong...
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Something went wrong", ButtonType.OK);
        alert.show();
    });

    new Thread(validatePassword).start(); // add the task to a thread and start it
});
```

Comment: &James_D Thank you, I am just learning multithreading and I thought the Task class worked different. I changed my code and it works now.

Comment: @TomášZajda See [documentation for the superclass, `Worker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Worker.html) for a description of the lifecycle.